# (Не)ограниченная — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

В буклете на стенде встретилось предложение  "**Неограниченная** расстоянием дальность связи, комфортное управление и настройка функций в одно касание дисплея телефона, расширенный сервис в комплексе с самыми продвинутыми на сегодняшний день технологиями делают охранную систему одним из лидеров на рынке".

Смутило написание  "неограниченная ", из-за чего разгорелся спор. В данном контексте  "не " пишется раздельно или слитно? И какое для этого существует правило?

Comment: Составителям буклета - двойка (смотри ответы).

Answer (score 3):

Правильно Вас смутило: "не ограниченная" в данном случае надо было написать раздельно. Почему? Есть зависимое слово "расстоянием", поэтому должно быть простое отрицание.

Возможно, я ошибаюсь, но исправил бы "в одно касание дисплея телефона" на "одним касанием...". Без слов "дисплея телефона" так, как сейчас, было бы хорошо: "настройка функций в одно касание".

Comment: И по-моему выражение "в одно касание" не может быть расширено  дополнением.

Comment: Это уже другая история - спор вызвала именно эта фраза. Спасибо!

Comment: Спор вызвала, как я понимаю, не вся фраза, а только одно слово (в оригинале: *неограниченная*). Так вот, грамматически корректно писать в этом случае раздельно с *не*, а стилистически вся фраза ошибочна, как показал @slava1947.

Comment: Да я понимаю, что слово, что Вы мне объясняете! Действительно, не подумал, что "неограниченная расстоянием" звучит нелепо.)))

Answer (score 1):

> "Неограниченная расстоянием дальность связи…"
>
> В данном контексте "не" пишется раздельно или слитно?

Гм… *Неограниченная расстоянием дальность...*?  Так [***дальность***](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x) и есть ***расстояние*** в одном из своих значений.

Думаю, что правильнее было бы написать примерно так:

***Практически неограниченная дальность связи...***

В таком контексте — слитно.

Comment: Я не тот, кто занимается правками и вообще имеет отношение к этому буклету, мне просто стало интересно. Если бы я отвечал за правки, то я бы конечно перекроил бы весь рекламный буклет, но увы:) Просто возник спор конкретно из-за этой фразы - мне активно доказывали, что в данном случае пишется слитно.